# Is there a clear problem as to why my delete_list function does not return an empty linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct node * delete_list(struct node * list)
{
 struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // allocates memory for temp

while (list != NULL)
{
    temp = list->next;
    free(list);
    list = temp;

}
free(temp);

return list;
}
```

I have tried working out my function by hand on paper and it seems to work. I tried an example linked list of length 3 and I have found my function to delete each node and have the list point to null at the end. The actual result does not reflect this.

Could someone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, include the code that builds the list, calls `delete_list` and then the code that verifies the result.

Comment: The `malloc` is unnecessary and results in a memory leak. `temp = list->next;` that will immediately lose the reference to the allocated memory and thus it can never be freed.

Comment: Also, what is the point of returning `list` when it  will always be `NULL`?

Comment: `The actual result does not reflect this` Post the test code that checks "*the actual result*".

Comment: better to make  `free(list); list = NULL; list = temp;`

Comment: @IrAM `list = NULL; list = temp;` is 100% equivalent to `list = temp;` so there is no point in doing *two* assignments there.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing more than you need to here.  The call to `malloc` is unnecessary and just leaks memory.  And the final call to `free` is also incorrect, since it will just attempt to free `NULL`.

All you need is the following:

```
void delete_list(struct node *list)
{
    struct node *temp;

    while (list != NULL) {
        temp = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = temp;
    }
}
```

This will free every node in the list, which is all it needs to do.

Note that I changed the return type to `void` since there's no reason for a constant `NULL` return value, but if you want to return `NULL` it's easy enough to do so.

Comment: Okay thank you for the comment. My CPSC professor wanted us to use dynamic memory so I assumed we had to use malloc. Is there a way to use dynamic memory in this function?

Comment: @CoolMcDougal It already is.  It's calling `free`, which is how you free memory allocated by `malloc`.  You obviously aren't going to allocate any memory here.  That would be done in the function that *creates* the list, not the function that deletes it.

Comment: I tried the example code you made changes to but my unit test still do not pass and I am not sure why.

Comment: @CoolMcDougal You have a bug in the rest of your code.  The code I posted has no bugs.  You only posted your `delete_list` function, so you'd need to show the rest of your code to find your remaining bugs.